# appKernel bug while upgrading Symfony 2.8 to 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.4

i'm upgrading my Symfony 2.8 project to the new LTS 3.4. I'm following  [symfony guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html) and [knpuniverty best practise structure](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/new-dir-structure#autoload-appkernel)

But i've some problem with AppKernel, when I launch composer install, after all bundle upgrade, i have this exception:

> [RuntimeException]
>     An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
>     PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found in /var/www/pitstop/app/AppKernel.php on line 7

but in my AppKernel.php Kernel class seem correctly imported. 
Someone can help me?

Comment: Is the vendor/Symfony directory actually populated i.e. does Kernel.php actually exist?  If so then it's a psr4 namespace issue.  You can try running "composer dump-autoload" and if that does not help then maybe update your question with the psr-4 section of composer.json.  Might also help to create a new 3.4 project and then compare the composer.json files.

Comment: for psr-4 section i followed knpuniversity instruction. Now i try to generate a 3.4 new project and copy composer.json. Now i have a problem with console, this; [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  
  Could not open input file: bin/console

Comment: my console is in app directory, if i move in bin directory nothing change

Comment: Yep.  I have not looked at the migrate link you gave.  As you have discovered, there are directory structure changes.  Simply copying the composer.json file is not going to help.  You could try copying the new 3.4 bin/console file over but even then you will probably just get a different error.  Normally when I make a major version upgrade I start fresh with a new project and then copy from my old project.  Trying to upgrade in place seldom works for me.

Comment: maybe is the better solution, i just consider my own setting but i already spend a day for this. i'll try this way.

Comment: I have had some success with creating a new project, copying code from the existing project, getting it to work and then copying whatever I had to change back to the original project.  That preserves source control history.